# Launch Appium with Command Line

Tags: node.js, appium

When I'm using Appium client, I checked the logs and the first command of this seems like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Mobil\Applications\eribank.apk --app-activity .LoginActivity --app-pkg com.experitest.ExperiBank --device-ready-timeout 300 --platform-name Android --platform-version 18 --automation-name Appium --device-name "emulator-5554" --log-no-color`. But I want to call this command from command line without Appium client. When I'm trying to '`node "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Mobil\Applications\eribank.apk" --app-activity .LoginActivity --app-pkg com.experitest.ExperiBank --device-ready-timeout 300 --platform-name Android --platform-version 18 --automation-name Appium --device-name "emulator-5554" --log-no-color`', I got the

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

There isn't file directory as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js". How can I call appium server by command myself? Thanks.

Comment: You make it work?

Comment: Hi @barbudito. I resolved the problem but I am sorry i couldn't remember how i did:/ it had been a while.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure and do not have access to my appium computer atm. I believe the issue is that you are trying to run a `.exe` file not the `lib\server\main.js` file. Meaning those paths should be separated.

Try running it as shown below:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" lib\server\main.js <rest of commandline arguments>`

Hope that solves your issue. Sorry I can't verify on my own setup.

Comment: lib\server\main.js instead of it "C:/Users/Web/AppData/Local/Programs/appium-desktop/resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"

Answer (score 0):

1. If you try to run appium without arguments, it works?

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" lib\server\main.js
   ```

You will have to see default values and appium started

```
[info] [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.7.0
[info] [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723[info] [HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
```

2. I don't know if it will work... But I think you are trying to run a different main.js... Default path for my appium-desktop v1.7.0 is

   ```
   C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js
   ```

Maybe if you try with absolute paths?

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" "C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js"
```